# HTML Buttons with animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml, animation

I'm trying to create several buttons that have 4-5 frames of animation in them, and rather than using the typical CSS method (where 1 image has both states, and CSS toggles between top and bottom), I was curious if anyone had an idea on how to do this with 4-5 frames rather than 2. Obviously CSS alone can't make this happen - but its becoming a real challenge to find ANY info on this. Because the images have individual animation, I can't simply use the opacity to fade into the new image, it has to contain all 4-5. Any help would be much appreciated!

Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at [k10k](http://www.k10k.net/) and see how the buttons in the top are done: animated png's and animated gifs ;)

[image: png]
[image: gif]

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to do this without JavaScript would be for the hover state to load an animated GIF for the background image.  Otherwise, you'd have to use something like jQuery to animate the `background-position` property instead.

Comment: any info on a jquery tutorial? Javascript is totally fine - I can't seem to find any info on that method that would apply to a button.. most are for animating actual objects in a div

Answer (score 1):

for this you'll need to use an animated GIF. if you don;'t have a animated GIF creation tool installed, either use Photoshop, which may be massive overkill, or one fo the free tools like [GIFted motion](http://www.onyxbits.de/giftedmotion)

Comment: i considered this, but applying the mouseOver action to GIF doesn't work, right? GIF images just repeat endlessly or run once, you can't tap into the mouseOver event with one image

Answer (score 0):

A very non-traditional frowned upon way this can be done is to...

-Animate them as a flash object. Export the xml/flash and imbed it into the htm